# Black Mesa achievements

Tags: achievements, black-mesa

What are the achievements in the new Half-Life 2 mod [Black Mesa](http://release.blackmesasource.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a list of achievements as reported from within the game's 'achievements' screen - I am not sure if this is a fully comprehensive list of achievements or whether there are additional hidden achievements.

There [is a page](http://wiki.blackmesasource.com/Achievements) on the Black Mesa: Source wiki, this has now been updated with information on these achievements.

---

Brownian Motion
*Pass the toilet paper to the scientist in need.*

Caffeine Extraction
*Perform a surgical caffeine extraction from 20 machines.* [0/20]

Calculated Trajectory
*Kill 10 Airborne Headcrabs using the Shotgun.* [0/10]

Centripetal Attraction
*Kill 20 enemies with the Hivehand.* [0/20]

Convection Refinement
*Ruin the microwave casserole.*

Dead Reckoning
*Kill an Assassin with the 357 Magnum.*

Digital Wizardry
*Kill 10 enemies with a reprogrammed Sentry.* [0/10]

Ethically Questionable
*Conduct all of the questionable research experiments.* [0/5]

Futile Resistance
*Kill 10 enemies with Snarks.* [0/10]

Gray Matter Propulsion
*Headshot 20 enemies with the .357 Magnum.* [0/20]

Hyper Saturation Conundrum
*Drown in Lambda Core's coolant.*

Inflammatory Actions
*Kill a Headcrab using fire.*

Kinetic Repulsion
*Kill a Marine with their own grenade.*

Mega Hertz
*Kill 5 enemies with one grenade.*

Nuclear Fishin'
*Kill an Icthyosaur with either the Tau or Gluon.*

Permeable Infrastructure
*Use the alternative path in the Office Complex.*

Premature Expulsion
*Use an entire clip of Gluon ammo in one continuous shot.*

Prophylactic Suggested
*Get overtaken by a Headcrab's amble anterior.*

Proverbial Tinkerer
*Interfere with the alarm and laptop in Anomalous Materials.*

Quantum Capacitance
*Overcharge it anyway.*

Rare Specimen
*Send the Hidden Hat to Xen.*

Remote Detonation
*Kill a Barnacle with a Satchel.*

Resonance Procrastinator
*Refuse to insert the specimen into the Anti-Mass Spectrometer.*

Unified Coupling Theorum
*Help the Barnacle and Headcrab find true love.* [0/10]

Universal Gravitation
*Get killed by your own Snarks.*