# How does one obtain these achievements in Black Mesa: Source?

Tags: achievements, black-mesa

Taken from [enter link description here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84991/black-mesa-achievements)

> **Quantum Capacitance**: Overcharge it anyway.
>
> **Remote Detonation**: Kill a Barnacle with a Satchel.
>
> **Unified Coupling Theorum**: Help the Barnacle and Headcrab find true
>   love. [*0/10*]
>
> **Permeable Infrastructure**: Use the alternative path in the Office
>   Complex.

I'm having trouble with these four in Black Mesa: Source.  I have already completed all the other achievements, but these have stumped me.

What exactly is a Barnacle?  Do they mean Headcrabs?  I'm very confused.

Comment: Hi, Retrosaur. Asking about *every single achievement* is a bit much for a single question. As such, I'm reverting to your earlier revision, which listed only 4. Even that's pushing it a bit, though; you might have better luck asking 4 distinct questions, talking about what you've tried already, etc, if you're hoping to get the best answer.

Comment: Barnacles are the alien monsters that you see attached to the ceiling with a long slender grey "tongue" stretching down nearly to the floor, which they use to reel in their prey (or you). I haven't gotten the achievement but I suspect you need to get headcrabs to walk or jump into the barnacle's "tongue".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Quantum Capacitance

Hold the secondary fire button of the [**Tau Cannon**](https://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Tau_Cannon) weapon (right-click, by default). The weapon will then overcharge if you hold it for some time (you will know this as your health and shield will take a hit).

---

## Remote Detonation

This is a [barnacle](https://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Barnacle)

[image: barnacle]

And here is a [satchel charge](https://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Satchel_Charge):
[image: satchel charge]

Kill one of the former, with the latter.

---

## Unified Coupling Theorum

Lead a [headcrab](https://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Headcrab) to a barnacle's tentacles and have the barnacle eat/kill the headcrab.

---

## Permeable Infrastructure

There's an alternate route through the vents in the [Office Complex chapter](https://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Office_Complex). You need to go through that route to get this achievement. See this Youtube video on how to find that route: